# Python 2.7 vs 3.3 : Huge increase in time taken to read a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.3

For some reason, i had to downgrade to 2.7.
This simple piece of code took less than a second to read a file with about 100,000 records in python 3.3

```
with open(fileName) as sourceFile:
    for line in sourceFile:
        tempDict = self.createPositionLadderHash(line.rstrip().split(","))
        self.addToPositionsDictionary(tempDict)
    return self.POSITIONS_MAP
```

However, after downgrading to 2.7, it is taking over 5 seconds. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Automatically decoded? H went from 3.3 to 2.7, not the other way around.

Comment: @jsbueno: ah, indeed.

Comment: Of course if this class explicitly deals with Unicode, and decodes all the strings somewhere in `createPositionLadderHash` or `addToPositionsDictionary`, it's possible that the issue is with how he's decoding in 2.7 vs. the implicit decoding in 3.3 (especially since 3.3 can often be blazingly fast by decoding UTF-8 into UTF-8…).

Comment: What do `createPositionLadderHash` and `addToPositionsDictionary` do? Are they dependent on the encoding of the file contents? Python 3.3 decodes the contents automatically to unicode. It could also be you rely on certain functions returning iterators in python 3, but return lists (processing everything at once) in Python 2.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you sure it's the file reading that's the problem? What happens if you replace `tempDict = self.createPositionLadderHash(line.rstrip().split(","))` with `tempDict = {}`, or remove the `addToPositionsDictionary` line? Is it still 5x slower in 2.7 vs. 3.3?

Comment: @abarnert: decoding UTF-8 into UTF-8?  :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: In 3.3, Unicode strings have a representation that can be any one or more of UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32, instead of specifically being UTF-16 (or, for wide builds, UTF-32). So, if you do `foobytes.decode('utf-8')` often it's just building a `str` object that points to the same UTF-8 buffer. (If someone later needs the UTF-16 bytes—e.g., to call a Windows API function—it'll have to convert at that point, of course. But often that never happens.)

Comment: @abarnert: ah, right. For all-latin-1 input it can just copy that straight to a string (decoding the 2-byte latin-1 points to 1 byte per char in-memory).

Comment: In a quick test, reading 655360 lines of pure ASCII as `str` and doing nothing else (`deque(open(path), maxlen=0)`) takes 46ms in 3.3, 47ms in 2.7 (but 101ms in 3.2). So, I'm getting a 2% slowdown from 3.3 to 2.7… but not a 5x slowdown.

Comment: Also, if there's code dealing with newline issues… If you've got some code that's a lot faster in the case where newlines are already Unix-style, and you're feeding it mixed newlines, 3.3 has universal newline support on by default, but 2.7 doesn't (and enabling it takes that 47ms up to 80ms).

Comment: thanks guys. In fact the entire program has slowed down drastically. Seems like i'm missing something obvious here. How do i force the application to read the file as UTF-8 characters?